# Why I am getting an empty string?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to put the output of the bash command in a variable but I get an empty string.

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output("echo hello world", shell=True)
print out + ' ok'
```

the output is:

```
hello world
 ok
```

instead of:

```
hello world
hello world ok
```

why does this happen?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(["echo","hello world"])` will work without the need for shell=True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is that subprocess commands *add a newline*. It may be clumsy, but try this:

```
print out.rstrip('\n') + ' ok'
```

Comment: to be clear: the newline is introduced by `echo` itself, not `subprocess` module e.g., [`echo -n abc` does not add a newline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28394197/4279) (if `echo` supports `-n` parameter)

Answer (score 3):

The output of `echo` includes a newline. The result is *not* written to your terminal, the output is captured by `check_output()`, but you then print that output including the newline:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.check_output("echo hello world", shell=True)
>>> out
'hello world\n'
```

giving you `'hello world'` and `' ok'` on two separate lines when printed.

You could remove the newline afterwards; using [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) would remove *all* whitespace from the start and end of the string, for example:

```
print out.strip() + ' ok'
```

On some shells, the `echo` command takes an `-n` switch to suppress the newline:

```
echo -n hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo` prints the text with a new line character `\n` appended to it. If you want to omit that, use `printf` instead.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.check_output("printf 'hello world'", shell=True)

>>> print out
>>> 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

You captured the output by invoking `check_output`. According to the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
    Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.
```